# Issue while looping 2D array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying a truly easy thing which is looping inside a 2D array and creating another array by checking row per row.

For example, my 2D array contains the hex colors of a range of cells from a Google Sheet. I want to check every line and verify if on of the element id either red or orange.

Here is my sample code :

```
var 2Darray = [ [ '#ff0000', '#000000', '#000000' ],
              [ '#000000', '#ff6d01', '#000000' ],
              [ '#000000', '#000000', '#000000' ] ]
var redHex = "#ff0000";
var orangeHex = "#ff6d01";

var newColors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rangeColor.length; i++) {
    var keepGoing  = true; 
    for (var j = 0; j < rangeColor[i].length; j++) {
        switch (rangeColor[i][j]) {
            case redHex:
                newColors[i] = redHex;
                console.log("1")
                keepGoing = false;
                break;
            case orangeHex:
                newColors[i] = orangeHex;
                console.log("2");
                keepGoing = false;
                break;
            case "#000000":
                newColors[i] = "#000000";
                console.log("3")
                keepGoing = false;
                break;
        }
        if (!keepGoing) {
          break;
        } 
    }
}    
console.log(newColors);
```

My new array should be : `[ '#ff0000', '#ff6d01', '#000000' ]` but is `[ '#ff0000', '#000000', '#000000' ]` which indicates that there is an issue with my loop but I can't figure out what. Maybe the break behavior with double for loop ?

Comment: whats `rangeColor.length`?

Comment: What is rangeColor variable you are referring to?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your script, if `2Darray` is `rangeColor`, in your script, how about removing `keepGoing = false;` in `case "#000000":`? Because when the 2nd element of the array is checked, only the 1st element is checked because `keepGoing = false;` at `case "#000000":`. If `2Darray` is `rangeColor`, I think that by this modification, `[ '#ff0000', '#ff6d01', '#000000' ]` is obtained. If I misunderstood your script, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your script, if `2Darray` is `rangeColor`, in your script, how about removing `keepGoing = false;` in `case "#000000":` as follows?

Because when the 2nd element of the array is checked, only the 1st element is checked because `keepGoing = false;` at `case "#000000":`. If `2Darray` is `rangeColor`, I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

And, in your script, I thought that `var newColors = [];` is required to be added.

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var newColors = [];
var rangeColor = [ [ '#ff0000', '#000000', '#000000' ],
              [ '#000000', '#ff6d01', '#000000' ],
              [ '#000000', '#000000', '#000000' ] ];
var redHex = "#ff0000";
var orangeHex = "#ff6d01";
for (var i = 0; i < rangeColor.length; i++) {
    var keepGoing  = true; 
    for (var j = 0; j < rangeColor[i].length; j++) {
        switch (rangeColor[i][j]) {
            case redHex:
                newColors[i] = redHex;
                console.log("1")
                keepGoing = false;
                break;
            case orangeHex:
                newColors[i] = orangeHex;
                console.log("2");
                keepGoing = false;
                break;
            case "#000000":
                newColors[i] = "#000000";
                console.log("3")
                // keepGoing = false; // Removed
                break;
        }
        if (!keepGoing) {
          break;
        } 
    }
}    
console.log(newColors);
```

As other method, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
var rangeColor = [
  ['#ff0000', '#000000', '#000000'],
  ['#000000', '#ff6d01', '#000000'],
  ['#000000', '#000000', '#000000']
];
var redHex = "#ff0000";
var orangeHex = "#ff6d01";

var newColors = rangeColor.map(r => r.includes(redHex) ? redHex : r.includes(orangeHex) ? orangeHex : '#000000');
console.log(newColors) // ==> [ '#ff0000', '#ff6d01', '#000000' ]
```

#### References:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks, really like your second method ! I'm not very used to js.

Answer (score 1):

I am considering a typo in your question that 2Darray = rangeColor.

It is because, you are breaking your inner loop in the first iteration itself every time. And hence your answer is the first element of each row.